# grading of quantum plan

Tags: noncommutative-geometry

I can not understand a paragraph of this book:

Answer (score 2):

The grading is just the degree of the polynomials in the usual sense.

Comment: can you write it in more detailes?

Comment: why they are homogenous of degree 2?

Comment: $q$ is just a number (well, an element of $k$).  So $x y - q y x$ is a homogeneous second degree polynomial.